# Where third-party keyboards store their font

Tags: android, android-keypad, android-fonts

Nowadays third party keyboards for rooted android device are already included third party font(eg. Myanmar, Vietnam) and they installed those fonts together with keyboards. For my projects, I have to know where those applications are storing their font.

I already searched in android file manager with .ttf keyword. But I cannot find out those true type fonts that I already installed them. Can someone help me? In which directory do third party keyboards save their fonts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any application, not just keyboards, can include fonts in its assets, and these fonts can be used directly from there - there is no need to copy or install them anywhere.

See the method Typeface:createFromAsset() http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Typeface.html